# Unable to map protobuf string field to BigQuery's geography field in a subscription writing to a bigquery table

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, protocol-buffers, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

**Problem description**
We have created a pub/sub topic in Google Cloud Platform where a subscription should write directly to a BigQuery table using the option *Delivery type*: "Write to BigQuery".

The topic uses a proto3 schema as follows

```
syntax = "proto3";

message ProtocolBuffer {
  ...
  optional string location = 3;
  ...
}
```

and the BigQuery table the subscription should write to contains a nullable column `location` with type `GEOGRAPHY`.

Now when trying to create the subscription, the following error is thrown:
`Incompatible schema type for field 'location': field is STRING in the topic schema, but GEOGRAPHY in the BigQuery table schema.`

How could we fix this problem without changing the `GEOGRAPHY` type of the `location` column in BigQuery? Ideally, you do not want to use Dataflow, the old way of writing from a subscription to BigQuery due to financial reasons.

There are two Google Cloud Platform sources we could find to try and solve this problem.

**Schema mapping** 
https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/bigquery#schema_compatibility

This documentation tells us there is no existing mapping from proto3's `string` to ZetaSQL's `GEOGRAPHY`.

**Data type conversion** 
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/write-api#data_type_conversions

On the other side of the mapping, BigQuery's data conversion documentation notes that `GEOGRAPHY` is converted to proto's `string`. However, we get an error after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cloud Pub/Sub BigQuery subscription does not currently support the GEOGRAPHY type, which is what is indicated by the error. Unfortunately, there is no solution at this time other than using a Dataflow pipeline or changing the type in the BigQuery table. You could also add a feature request in the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:187173&s=created_time:desc).

Comment: An issue has been created in the Google issue tracker here: [https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/261481063](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/261481063)