# Pub/Sub Bigquery subscriptions schema with GEOGRAPHY fields

Tags: google-bigquery, publish-subscribe

I testes pub/sub BigQuery subscriptions with normal string, integer and other typical field types, but I can't find a way to push GEOMETRY field types.
With Streaming I use geoJSON format and send it as string and BigQuery does the conversion to GEOMETRY, but with Pub/Sub when I try to have GEOMETRY on BigQuery and String on AVRO Pub/Sub got an error message:

> Incompatible schema type for field 'gps': field is STRING in the topic
> schema, but GEOGRAPHY in the BigQuery table schema.

How can this be done? Any suggestion?

Regards,

Rui

Comment: not sure if that answer applies, but see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74703350/unable-to-map-protobuf-string-field-to-bigquerys-geography-field-in-a-subscript

Comment: Thanks Michael, that's exactly the same problem using Proto instead of Avro, but the problem is the same. It seems there is no current solution and a Fix request was issues.